# tableview select row after reload data infinite loop

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I have a tableView with a list of textField in every cell and I use the UITextFieldDelegate.
The user can write that he wants and add row.

The problem is that the tableview must be reload to show the result to the user, but it break the becomeFirstResponder()...

I have try this solution  after `self.tableView.reloadData()`:

1

```
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cell.identifier, for: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)) as! Cell
textFieldDidBeginEditing(cell.textFiedl)
```

2

```
let cell = tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath) as! CellItemOptions
cell.nameOptionsItem.becomeFirstResponder()
```

3

```
let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CellItemOptions
cell.nameOptionsItem.becomeFirstResponder()
```

But it doesn't work.

Thank you for your help !

**EDIT : my code**

```
import UIKit

class OptionsItemViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    var textFiedlDelegate: UITextField? = nil
    var categorySelected: Category?
    var options: [String] = []
    var nameOptions: [String] = []
    var cellSelected: Int = 0
    var viewHeight: CGFloat = 0
    var selectedRow: IndexPath? = nil
    var tableviewNeedToReload: Bool = false

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var keyboardAlwaysShow: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var newFeatureButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    private let db = DataBase()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.textFiedlDelegate?.delegate = self
        self.title = categorySelected!.name
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        db.getItemOptions(predicateFormat: "id == \(self.categorySelected!.id)", completion: { results in
            self.categorySelected = results.first!
            self.options = self.categorySelected!.options as! [String]
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(false)
        self.viewHeight = self.view.frame.size.height
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(false)
        var index = 0
        while index < self.options.count {
            if self.options[index] != "" {
                index += 1
            } else {
                self.options.remove(at: index)
            }
            db.setCategoryOptions(category: self.categorySelected!, options: self.options, index: cellSelected)
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func newFeature(_ sender: Any) {
        if self.options.last != "" {
            let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.options.count, section: 0)
            self.options.append("")
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            let cell = tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath) as! CellItemOptions
            cell.nameOptionsItem.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - TableView Functions

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return options.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let option = options[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellItemOptions.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CellItemOptions
        cell.nameOptionsItem.delegate = self
        cell.configureCell(with: option)
        return cell
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.cellSelected = options.index(of: textField.text!)!
        let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.cellSelected, section: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CellItemOptions
        cell.nameOptionsItem.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField.text! == "" {
            if self.options[cellSelected] != "" {
                db.setRemoveDetailsItem(category: self.categorySelected!, index: cellSelected)
            }
            self.options.remove(at: cellSelected)
        } else {
            self.options[cellSelected] = "\(textField.text!)"
            db.setAddDetailsItem(category: self.categorySelected!, index: cellSelected)
        }
        db.setCategoryOptions(category: self.categorySelected!, options: self.options, index: cellSelected)
    }

    // MARK: - Keyboard

    func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.size.height == self.viewHeight {
                self.view.frame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y != self.viewHeight {
                self.view.frame.size.height += keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
    }
}

class CellItemOptions: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier = "OptionsItemCell"

    @IBOutlet weak var nameOptionsItem: UITextField!

    private let tableView = OptionsItemViewController()

    func configureCell(with cell: String) {
        nameOptionsItem.text = cell
    }
}
```

The problem, with this code, is the memory used increse, and the CPU is used around 100 % !! I think that I have create a infinite instruction, but i don't find it...

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, #3 is definitely the one you want. #1 and #2 are both only meant to be called by the table view to actually set up the cells. You should not be calling them directly. #3 asks the tableview for an already existing cell (if that index path is visible) which is what you want here.

The code for #3 looks okay on its own, so the issue may be somewhere else, can you post the rest of the code that gets called when you're reloading?